# How does a ThreadPool work with passed variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

i am currently trying to accept incoming connections through a thread pool and it all works but raised the following question:

What if i get a new connection before the thread pool handles the previous one.
Is the Object passed to the function, in this case client, replaced with the new connection or will it remember both?

the reason i think it forgets the first client is because the passed variable is just a reference right?

The code looks like this:

```
public static void Initialize()
    {
        socket.Start();

        System.Threading.Thread newConnection = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (isOnline)
            {
                System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = socket.AcceptTcpClient();
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleNewClient, client);
            }
        })
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "newConnection",
            Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
        };
    }
```

I hope this made it clear for you guys.
Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Comment: `socket` is not defined as argument, so it is a class scope or static. That is generally a bad idea. socket should be disposeable, and the rule for those are: "Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using block". The one exception I could think off are log files - or rather, they are more or less responsible for the entire application as "use" range.

Comment: You marked the function as void, wich is a potential issue. With Multitasking in all flavors, accidentally swallowing exceptions is a huge issue. Unless the thread pool takes care of catching and exposing exceptions, you are going to have an issue.

Comment: Mutli**threading** seems also to go overboard, as there is nothing CPU bound. This can propably be done with mere async. Then the whole idea of throwing a thread pool makes no sense. They got one *shared* socket. Multiple things working on one resource is just going to cause issues. It really seem like going Multithreading with a Thread Pool is a XY Problem.

Comment: @Christopher First of all thank you for the quick response. Secondly this is the part where i catch new connections and copy the socket to their own thread and handle everything from there. i cant have multiple threads listen to the same port accepting clients right? or use multiple tasks that go in order waiting on each other?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are basically trying to reinvent the WebServer or somthing close to it. My first advice is to never reinvent the wheel, if you got a fully gassed up car just standing there, keys in the ignition.

And especially web things have been solve dozens of times.

But if you got to do it yourself, generally you would get:

- one public port
- one thread that does nothing but listening to the Port, putting all it is receiving into a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1), [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) or similar construct.
- A giant Threadpool. We are talking about 50-100 Threads *per CPU core* on the average ASP.Net server.
- those threads will then start looking into the queue if there is anything to do. You want to assign each client a different port, to keep the connections appart. And maybe even try to have 1 thread process each request from start to finish (however, there is no guarantee for that in practice; expect the responsible thread to change).

A negotiation would go somewhat like this:

- Client to port 80: "Hey, I want to talk"
- Server figures and locks a random, unused port: "Okay, you can talk to me on port 54321".
- Client to port 54321: "Okay, here is what I want..."

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a gateway that manages all client connections and communicates itself with multiple servers in the network. It all does this already even in the way you described above. 
one public port for beginning connections and redirect it to a new one.
the giant thread pool i should look into now i use a class that runs and manages one client.

Comment: the code in this post is the thread listening for new clients and was just wondering what would happen if 2 clients on precisely the same time connect. like this I suspect it would all come down crashing. but what i understand is this is the way to do it.

new connection go to new thread and port done.

Comment: @JorisdeVos "if 2 clients on precisely the same time connect" They can connect shortly after another, but not at the same time. Between the Networking Hardware being only full-duplex or even half-duplex and the Windows Networking stack making sure you only geet complete packages, you never really have to worry about those details.

Comment: awesome! This was what i was looking for. Please post this as answer and ill accept it. Thanks again.